# Spring. Как корректно читать значения из файла конфигурации?

Tags: java, spring

Есть файл конфигурации src\main\resources\application.properties

В файле конфигурации есть значение:
reservation.list.get.max.value=25

Есть класс

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class AppProperties {

    @Value("${reservation.list.get.max.value}")
    public static int RESERVATION_LIST_GET_MAX_VALUE;
}
```

при получении всегда 0

```
int appMax = AppProperties.RESERVATION_LIST_GET_MAX_VALUE;
```

Как корректно читать значения из файла конфигурации?

Comment: Посмотрите, [это](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56321759/9719337) то, что вы ищете? а именно, как задать путь к контексту

Comment: путь к контексту с дефолтным расположением и названием файла конфигурации задавать не нужно, спринг и сам умеет найти конфигурацию в стандартном ее виде. уберите строку @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties") и попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Не уверен, что Spring в принципе позволяет засетить public static поле, можно, конечно, добавить сеттер для этого поля и аннотацию перенести на него, но в целом ваш вариант использования - плохая практика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public static int RESERVATION_LIST_GET_MAX_VALUE;

Проблема в static. Spring не использует @Value для static-fields.

Попробуйте это:

```
  @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
    public class AppProperties {
        public static Integer RESERVATION_LIST_GET_MAX_VALUE;

        @Value("${reservation.list.get.max.value}")
        private void setReservationListGetMaxValue(Integer number) {
            RESERVATION_LIST_GET_MAX_VALUE = number;
        }
    }
```